# Connect Android through active sync with Exchange server

Tags: email, android, exchange

I have troubles connecting my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2) to our Exchange server using the stock mail app. A colleague of mine also has an S4 and he has no troubles connecting it, using the same Android version etc. This is what I see in the debug log:

```
Logger 
Logger     -------------- New Log --------------
Logger     Model      :GT-I9505
Logger     Build      :I9505XXUEMKF
Logger     ChangeList :2082040
Logger     -------------------------------------
2013-12-30 17:56:50:792 7910 9120 [AsyncTask #1] ExchangeService| !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
2013-12-30 17:56:50:796 7910 7910 [main] ExchangeService| !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
2013-12-30 17:56:50:802 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| Testing EAS: owa.ithost.be, ithost\ooms.veerle;null, ssl = 1
2013-12-30 17:56:50:812 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EmailProxy| host = null
2013-12-30 17:56:50:819 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EmailProxy| port = 0
2013-12-30 17:56:50:820 7910 9662 [Binder_4] ExchangeService| getClientConnectionManager ssl = true, port = 443
2013-12-30 17:56:50:826 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EasSynService| create and return deviceType : SAMSUNGGTI9505
2013-12-30 17:56:50:829 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EmailProxy| host = null
2013-12-30 17:56:50:830 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EasSynService| getUserAgent()
2013-12-30 17:56:50:831 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| sendHttpClientOptions(): URI String:https://owa.myServer.be/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?Cmd=OPTIONS&User=myDomain%5CUser.Name&DeviceId=SEC19D1971555700&DeviceType=SAMSUNGGTI9505
2013-12-30 17:56:50:832 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| Authorization:***********
2013-12-30 17:56:50:834 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| MS-ASProtocolVersion:2.5
2013-12-30 17:56:50:835 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| Connection:keep-alive
2013-12-30 17:56:50:836 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| User-Agent:SAMSUNG-GT-I9505/101.403
2013-12-30 17:56:50:842 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EmailProxy| host = null
2013-12-30 17:56:50:845 7910 9662 [Binder_4] EmailProxy| port = 0
2013-12-30 17:56:50:847 7910 9662 [Binder_4] ExchangeService| getClientConnectionManager ssl = true, port = 443
2013-12-30 17:57:05:874 9094 9104 [Binder_1] EmailProvider| EmailProvider.query: uri=content://com.android.email.provider/hostauth?limit=1, selection : protocol="eas" match: 16384
2013-12-30 17:57:05:927 7910 9120 [AsyncTask #1] ExchangeService| !!! EAS ExchangeService, stopping self
2013-12-30 17:57:30:888 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| executePostWithTimeout(): Unexpected exception org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
2013-12-30 17:57:30:890 7910 9662 [Binder_4] AbstractSyncService<825>| IOException caught: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
2013-12-30 17:57:30:898 7910 7910 [main] ExchangeService| !!! EAS ExchangeService, onDestroy
2013-12-30 17:57:30:900 7910 7910 [main] DiscourseLogger| Service=destroyed sStop=false sServiceThread=Died
2013-12-30 17:57:30:925 9094 9377 [AsyncTask #3] EmailServiceProxy| validate returns 1
2013-12-30 17:57:30:928 9094 9094 [main] Email| message : null
2013-12-30 17:57:30:936 9094 9094 [main] DiscourseLogger| email=user@aDifferentDomain.be status=failure reason=Cannot connect to server
2013-12-30 17:57:32:699 9094 9094 [main] Email| EmailFeature    CscFeature_Email_EnableOnDeviceHelp: false
2013-12-30 17:57:33:693 9094 9094 [main] Email| EmailFeature    CscFeature_Email_EnableOnDeviceHelp: false
2013-12-30 17:57:34:213 9094 9094 [main] Email| EmailFeature    CscFeature_Email_EnableOnDeviceHelp: false
2013-12-30 17:57:39:438 9094 9094 [main] Email| EmailFeature    CscFeature_Email_EnableOnDeviceHelp: false
2013-12-30 17:57:39:441 9094 9094 [main] AccountSetupExchange| Had to set CBACert in onNext = null
2013-12-30 17:57:39:443 9094 9609 [AsyncTask #5] EmailProvider| EmailProvider.query: uri=content://com.android.email.provider/hostauth, selection : address like ? and login like ? and protocol not like "smtp" match: 16384
2013-12-30 17:57:39:447 9094 9609 [AsyncTask #5] EmailProvider| EmailProvider.query: uri=content://com.android.email.provider/account, selection : emailAddress='user@aDifferentDomain.be' COLLATE NOCASE match: 0
2013-12-30 17:57:39:464 9094 9094 [main] Email| AccountCheckSettingsFragment onActivityCreated
2013-12-30 17:57:39:465 9094 9094 [main] AccountCheckSettingsFragment| CM Test!!! default case= 4
2013-12-30 17:57:39:468 9094 9118 [AsyncTask #1] Email| Begin check of incoming email settings
2013-12-30 17:57:39:487 7910 7910 [main] DiscourseLogger| Service=created sStop=false
```

I tried connecting with the FQDN of our domain (myDomain.local) as I read this could be an issue. Also tried connecting without SSL. I'm sure my credentials are correct but it seems like the connection times out but I don't know why...

Comment: I had the same issue with a different client on a touchViz based Samsung phone. It worked only once and at that time it showed "preparing for inintial sync" or something. I had tried to reset the phone and connect thinking that it would work if it was again the "initial sync" but it didn't. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My firewall blocked the traffic between my phone and the Exchange server. That's why the connection timed out. After allowing Exchange traffic to pass, everything worked like a charm.